# jscroller up and jscroller endless

Tags: html, css

please help me to find a solution on this coding

```
<div id="side_forums_pane" class="side_pane" style="display:none; height:330px;width:260px">
   <div class="jscroller2_up jscroller2_speed-19 jscroller2_mousemove" style="height:105px;align:left;left:2px;right:2px;width:160px;overflow:hidden;">
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>                                                            
    </div>
    <div class="jscroller2_up_endless jscroller_speed-19">
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/>
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>                                        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For what problem you want solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the others have stated, the question is not so clear, but I do see a bad CSS specification for the DIV you have classed as "jscroller2_up jscroller2_speed-19 jscroller2_mousemove".

There is an inline style on that DIV that includes "align:left;"

This is not valid.

I assume your problem is a layout issue.  You can try to solve by correcting with the following:

```
<div id="side_forums_pane" class="side_pane" style="display:none; height:330px;width:260px"> 
   <div class="jscroller2_up jscroller2_speed-19 jscroller2_mousemove" style="height:105px; text-align:left; left:2px; right:2px; width:160px; overflow:hidden;"> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>                                                             
    </div> 
    <div class="jscroller2_up_endless jscroller_speed-19"> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/> 
       <b style="text-decoration:underline">Coming Soon..</b><br/> 
          Your Own Classifieds Section<hr size='1' color='silver'/>                                         
    </div> 
</div>
```

Note that the property is "text-align" and not "align"

Hope that's what you were looking for